# adb shell pm list packages missing some packages

Tags: android, adb

On Samsung device, if you install some themes, icon packs, etc in the Galaxy Theme app and do an adb shell pm list packages, the results are not found. Any ideas why? I've tried multiple switches and none work.

```
adb shell pm list packages | grep -i TZTY.xiyun.aodanimated
adb shell pm list packages TZTY.xiyun.aodanimated
```

However if i run this command, I can see it and even pull the apk

```
adb.exe shell pm dump TZTY.xiyun.aodanimated
```

```
DUMP OF SERVICE package:
Key Set Manager:
  [TZTY.xiyun.aodanimated]
      Signing KeySets: 238

Packages:
  Package [TZTY.xiyun.aodanimated] (64ebec8):
    userId=10422
    pkg=Package{79bbb3c TZTY.xiyun.aodanimated}
    codePath=/data/app/TZTY.xiyun.aodanimated-aBJscSanQXAT_FH9qo7qPQ==
    resourcePath=/data/app/TZTY.xiyun.aodanimated-aBJscSanQXAT_FH9qo7qPQ==
    legacyNativeLibraryDir=/data/app/TZTY.xiyun.aodanimated-aBJscSanQXAT_FH9qo7qPQ==/lib
    primaryCpuAbi=null
    secondaryCpuAbi=null
    versionCode=17 minSdk=21 targetSdk=21
    versionName=2
    splits=[base]
    apkSigningVersion=1
    applicationInfo=ApplicationInfo{4585b61 TZTY.xiyun.aodanimated}
    flags=[ ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ]
    privateFlags=[ PRIVATE_FLAG_REQUEST_LEGACY_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ]
    dataDir=/data/user/0/TZTY.xiyun.aodanimated
    supportsScreens=[small, medium, large, xlarge, resizeable, anyDensity]
    usesLibraries:
      org.apache.http.legacy
    usesLibraryFiles:
      /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar
    timeStamp=2020-08-14 12:14:26
    firstInstallTime=2020-08-14 12:14:28
    lastUpdateTime=2020-08-14 12:14:28
    installerPackageName=com.samsung.android.themecenter
    signatures=PackageSignatures{37ca686 version:1, signatures:[9b1d38ac], past signatures:[]}
    installPermissionsFixed=true
    pkgFlags=[ ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ]
    requested permissions:
      com.samsung.android.permission.SAMSUNG_OVERLAY_AOD
    User 0: ceDataInode=632630 installed=true hidden=false suspended=false stopped=true notLaunched=true enabled=0 instant=false virtual=false
      lastDisabledCaller: com.samsung.android.themecenter
      runtime permissions:
    User 10: ceDataInode=0 installed=false hidden=false suspended=false stopped=true notLaunched=true enabled=0 instant=false virtual=false
      runtime permissions:
```

Comment: Hi did u find a way to pull Samsung theme or stickers apk files ? as i am facing same issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To list all packages, you can use dumpsys:

`dumpsys package | grep "Package \["`

The command return, on my phone 219 entries while `pm list packages` return 183.

If you need only packages names:

`dumpsys package | grep "Package \[" | cut -d "\[" -f2 | cut -d "\]" -f1`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know what is the reason behind that? In my case pm returned 157 packages while dumpsys 158. Missing package was an app that I've recently installed with adb, although I don't recall seeing this issue on my previous HW / emulators, so I'm curious about root cause.

Comment: The command `pm list packages` list only installed third party applications. By default the argument `-3`, which list third party apps only, is used . `dumpsys` list all packages including: disabled, system and third party apps.

Comment: Try "pm list packages -a"

Comment: @JohnyTex, "pm list packages -a" does not show disabled packages.